# multiple threads that search a section of an array

Tags: java, multithreading

i am given the following code that makes a large array and finds that max value.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

class FindMax {
private static final int N = 256 * 1024 * 1024;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    assert(N > 0);

    int array[] = new int [N];

    assert(array != null);

    Random random = new Random(new Date().getTime());

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt();
    }

    Date start = new Date();

    int max = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    Date end = new Date();

    System.out.println("max: " + max);
    System.out.println("time in msec: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
}
```

I am to alter the code to make it faster by making multiple threads that each find the max value of a section of the array and then the main thread find the max value of the max values found by the threads.  This is what i have come up with so far.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

class FindMax extends Thread{
private static final int N = 256 * 1024 * 1024;

static int array[] = new int [N];
static int max = array[0];

public void run(){
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    assert(N > 0);
    int ts = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


    assert(array != null);

    Random random = new Random(new Date().getTime());

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt();
    }

    Date start = new Date();

    Thread t[] = new Thread[ts];
    for( int p=0; p<ts;p++){
        t[p] = new FindMax();
        t[p].start();
    }





    Date end = new Date();

    System.out.println("max: " + max);
    System.out.println("time in msec: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
}
```

i am not understanding this, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're not having each thread operating on a portion of the array, nor is your result set (`array`) threadsafe in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start. The next thing you need to do is give the `FindMax` class two member variables to represent the beginning and end of the range to search. Use those two member variables in place of `1` and `N` in the `for` loop. Then give `FindMax` a constructor with which you can set the two values. Then in the loop that constructs the `FindMax` objects, give each one a unique range to search. Finally, give `FindMax` a member variable to store the max value in, so that `main()` can query the max value found by each `FindMax`.

You'll probably want to use the `join()` method of the `Thread` class -- it waits for a `Thread` to finish before returning.

Comment: thanks! i got it done, but it has the opposite desired effect. i could  not fit the code in this comment box, so i posted a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448587/why-does-this-programs-speed-not-increase